# WSO2 - Asterisk in template param of API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a GET resouce as "/busqueda/{busqueda}" in API Manager 2.2.0, when i send an asterisk in the param 'busqueda' i receive =>

```
"STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 404, ERROR_MESSAGE = No matching resource found for given API Request"
```

** this work fine : busqueda="id:3,name~jhon"

** this not work : busqueda="id:3,name~*jhon"

Thanks.

Comment: How do you test the API? Are you calling the API via a program or different tool?

Comment: I call the API with Angular HttpClient, and test with SoapUI too, in both cases the same happen.. I can see the url intercepting http request and is fine, but for some reason api manager can not interpret it as a simple parameter, when i remove the asterisk from my string work fine.

Comment: excecuting the test with the curl generated by API store fail too... (only with asterisk)

Comment: Try to enable wire logs in API Manager and check the request which is received in API Manager. To enable wire logs you can follow the document: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Setting+Up+Logging

Comment: Would you try to url-encode the asterix? Using asterix as path parameter may be misinterpreted

Comment: I changed "~*" for a flag and evaluate it in backend.
Thanks all!